# which order is better for field declaring

Tags: java

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AbstractDbClient.class);

protected Connection connection;


protected Connection connection;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AbstractDbClient.class);
```

which order is better for field declareing? some books pointed that should order them by private/public/protected/etc, if base on this , the second code is better, but it seems looked bad. If incluse static final var or static var? which order rule is?

Comment: Check how is it done in open source projects. Why? Because if you want to share code (which you will), it's better to do it in a way that other people are used to.

Comment: I check some open source code, but it had no law . every coder has own style. I know some books say should order them by access-modifier, but I think constants define should befroe other's , then group them by access-modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I like all my statics at the top of a class and have all fields in public, protected, default, private order.

eg

```
public static final Integer a;
private static final Integer b;

public Integer c;
Integer d
private Integer d;
```

I also tend to add a line between teh statics and non static fields.

But it is a matter of opinion. Perhaps ask your peers whom you work with. It's better to be consistent on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you keep it consistent, but I prefer to arrange fields in the order they are set as this makes it easier to understand the code and debug it. IMHO.

```
 static final fields

 final fields

 mutable fields.
```

Comment: much truth into this, if the case is multithreaded- you don't wish the final fields cache-lines to be modified. Overall the data layout is an important piece of art when it comes to concurrency.

Comment: As is making the mutable fields as obvious as possible, which is why I group them.

Answer (score 4):

A common standard is to put all public variables on top, followed by protected, and then private. Some people put class/static variables on top before instance variables, and some put them after.

If you are working in a team that's writing new code, it would be best to get together and decide on a common convention. If you already have existing code that you are adding to, then go through it and figure out what convention the previous authors followed. You don't want a mix of styles in the same codebase.

Answer (score 2):

Data layout actually has performance properties, besides ordering the fields as you feel comfortable with.
I tend to follow something like:

- static final fields,
- static fields
- final fields
- modifiable fields
- volatile fields grouped by use cases

and sometimes

```
private field usedOnlyInFoo
method foo(){
}
```

[More on the topic](https://sites.google.com/site/1024cores/home/lock-free-algorithms/false-sharing---false) why data layout matters. While there is no formal way to enforce data layout in Java besides arrays/Direct Buffers usually the compiler (JVM) places the fields in their declaration order.